# How to become a werewolf after you join the dawngaurd?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I just got the game and I heard that you can become a werewolf by joining the companions, but it is to late for me and I don't want to start the game over.

Answer (score 7):

**It is not too late for you**. You are allowed to be a member of all of the guilds in Skyrim (well, you can't be a vampire lord and also a member of the Dawnguard). You don't have to commit to just one.

You can be a member of the Companions, the Dawnguard, Thieve's Guild, and Dark Brotherhood all at the same time. Joining the Dawnguard does not lock you out of the Companions.

Comment: In another question he mentioned that he attacked Whiterun with the Stormcloaks, and that it caused the companions questline to fail. Maybe he is asking this because he hopes the dawnguard can make him into a werewolf.

Answer (score -1):

Just complete some of the quests for the Companions and at some point in the quests you become part of the Circle and they will turn you into a werewolf